# Efficiency when running through a result set

Tags: php, mysql

when running through a result set, how efficient is this approach as compared to other methods?

```
for ($iCont=0; $iCont < mysql_num_rows($this->rsQuery); $iCont++)
{
      mysql_data_seek($this->rsQuery,$iCont);
      $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($this->rsQuery);
      //more things here like write row or push it to a global array
}
```

Is there any efficiency problem using mysql_data_seek even if it's done in an ordered sequence?

How about mysql_num_rows() at the beginning? does is affect?

So, are there better approaches?

What I want to implement is a method to return an associative array with all the result set content and another one to create a grid (html table) with the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it this is more efficient but looks nicer

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->rsQuery))
{
    //do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) returns a row or null if no more rows are returned, a simple while loop is sufficent:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->rsQuery)) {
 // ...
}
```